# How to set a default content type for a subsite in SharePoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a sub-site in SharePoint 2007 that contains a number of document libraries.  As of now, all newly created documents have a general content type.  I have created a new document for this specific sub-site and was hoping to set this new type as the default for all of my document libraries in this sub-site.  Is there an easy way to do this?  Or do I have to set it manually for each individual document library.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is create a new [List Template](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA100991561033.aspx), and create all your new libraries based off of that, instead of the standard Document Library template.